# How to sum random.choices?

Tags: python

I have a list of songs:

```
my_favorite_songs = [
    ['Waste a Moment', 3.03],
    ['New Salvation', 4.02],
    ['Staying\' Alive', 3.40],
    ['Out of Touch', 3.03],
    ['A Sorta Fairytale', 5.28],
    ['Easy', 4.15],
    ['Beautiful Day', 4.04],
    ['Nowhere to Run', 2.58],
    ['In This World', 4.02],
```

My task is to find a sum of 3 random songs?
Can you please help me with that?

I tried this res = sum(random.choices(time, k=3)), but had an error.

Comment: What is this `time` that you are randomly choosing from? Also -- don't just tell us that you had an error, tell us *what* the error is.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sum([x[1] for x in random.choices(my_favorite_songs, k=3)])
```

Comment: but what if it is listed like this?
my_favorite_songs = {
    'Waste a Moment': 3.03,
    'New Salvation': 4.02,
    'Staying\' Alive': 3.40,
    'Out of Touch': 3.03,
    'A Sorta Fairytale': 5.28,
    'Easy': 4.15,
    'Beautiful Day': 4.04,
    'Nowhere to Run': 2.58,
    'In This World': 4.02,
}